# Hid Global.Multi-ISO Mifare reader Binary Protocol

Tags: c#, protocols, nfc, rfid, mifare

can any one explain how the binary protocol of HID-MULTI-ISO Mifare reader works?

I am sending a frame to MIFARE reader (HID HF multi-ISO reader), but it failed. according to the datasheet, the frame looks like this:

```
>> 020101787803
```

where `02` is the STX, `01` is the device ID, `78` is the data which is a command `reset` and the other `78` is the  BCC (block check character) which is the result of 01,01 and 78 xored. and the last `03` is the ETX.

when i send the frame it results error `? ? ?` meaning command error.

i am familiar with the ASCII protocol and it is working well but i want to do the reader configuration using binary protocols, which involves frames.

any answer is appreciated..

Comment: That is not the protocol of the Mifare 1K. It is the protocol of your reader you are using. Unfortunately you haven't named the reader..

Comment: @NilsPipenbrinck, it is a HID HF Multi ISO Reader, sorry i forgot to mention before.